# VB.net: Extract and replace all instances of HTML

Tags: .net, regex, vb.net, replace

I am working on manipulating/extracting data from well-formed HTML in one of our legacy systems.  I need to use regex to parse the HTML, find certain patterns, extract the data, and return some modified HTML.  I know that regex and HTML are never the answer but, given that I know exactly where the data is coming from and that the data is properly structure, I am confident that this will work for the particular situation.

The HTML that I am working with has the following pattern:

```
<i>Name1</i>: Some text goes here<br/>
<i>Name2</i>: Some different text goes here<br/>
<i>Name3</i>: Some other different text goes here<br/>
```

I need to change the HTML to the following:

```
<i>Name1</i><p>Some text goes here</p>
<i>Name2</i><p>Some different text goes here</p>
<i>Name3</i><p>Some other different text goes here</p>
```

Basically, I want to take the inner text, wrap it in a p tag and then remove the trailing br.

I want to do something like the following:

```
Dim HTML as String = [The HTML goes here]
html = Regex.Replace(html, "</i>:(.+?)<br\s*\/?>", "</i><p>(.+?)</p>", RegexOptions.Multiline)
```

but it obviously isn't working.

In VB.net, how do I replace all desired instances of HTML with the new HTML?

Comment: Try [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/). I personally never tried it myself, but it was suggested many times here, so it must be good enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a shot:

```
Dim HTML as String = [The HTML goes here]
Dim evaluator As MatchEvaluator = Function(m As Match)
                                  Return "</i><p>" & m.Groups(1).Value & "</p>"
                                  End Function
html = Regex.Replace(html, "</i>:(.+?)<br\s*\/?>", evaluator, RegexOptions.Multiline)
```

Comment: that `regex` shot can bring down the whole `app`

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to parse and manipulate HTML (in particular if the format of the HTML is not regular). The source download comes with a bunch of example projects, so you can see how to use it.

In general [Regex is not a good solution for parsing HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1583).